# How do I change a listview list item's theme dynamically in jQuery Mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a split-list listview with something like a name and then a STAR icon as the split button.

When a user clicks the STAR icon I want to change the star to turn yellow (or something), and also change the list item to turn that color as well.

I'm unsure how to change that list item theme dynamically. I've tried changing the data-theme of the list item like this

```
$("#my_list_item").attr("data-theme","d");
```

and then even calling listview('refresh') but that doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by changing the attribute of "li" and by triggering mouseout event.

```
$("#my_list_item").attr("data-theme","d").trigger('mouseout');
```

If you want to change the theme of all the list elements inside a list, use

```
$("#my_list li").attr("data-theme","d").trigger('mouseout');
```

Here is the working jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ChaitanyaMunipalle/5yjZV/

Comment: That works well. But what if you then want to switch it back to the original theme? I tried with this but it didn't work:

$("#my_list li").attr("data-theme","d").trigger('mouseout');

Answer (score 5):

you can use:

```
$(id).buttonMarkup({theme:'a'});
```

to change.
If you want to restore to the old theme, simply replace old them.

Answer (score 1):

Try the trigger('create') method

```
$("#my_list_item").attr("data-theme","d").trigger('create');
```

Answer (score 0):

1. remove list item's button up and down theme. (ex. ui-btn-up/down-"swatch theme character")
2. add new theme to the list item's button up and down theme.
3. set the new theme of the list item.  (ex. $(li).attr("data-theme", "swatch theme character")
4. refresh the listview.
5. trigger mouseout event on list item.

[Source](http://blog.vawterconsultingservices.com/index.cfm/2012/5/13/Refresh-jQuery-Mobile-Listview-Themes-at-Runtime)